# three.js issue regarding sprites, sprite materiel, and mouse clicks

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hello and thanks for your time. I have just read multiple tutorials regarding clicking objects with the mouse in three.js. Unfortunately there was no mention if this is possible with sprites. As a workaround I attempted to apply a .png image to a plane geometry. While this worked as far as click-ability is concerned it looked very sloppy and didn't auto rotate towards the camera. Dose an object have to have a mesh to be clickable and if so is there any way to apply a invisible mesh to a sprite? Or any other workaround. I assume I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For billboarding effects -- for the plane to face the camera -- set the rotation of the plane equal to the rotation of the camera.